# mathematical expressions as enum type JAVA

Tags: java

I just want to know if i define

```
public enum Op {-,+}
```

can I pick out one of them and do math like `4 +Op[0] +3` would return `1` instead of `4-3`, however it is asking for identifier too

Comment: That code would not even compile...

Comment: You can do something like that with enum. But it requires a lot more code than that. An enum is not an array, and Java does not support operator overloading.

Comment: nothing new i could check it in my compiler too, i would like to hear some reasonable answer Thanks

Comment: You should accept the answer if you got your answer and solves what you want

Answer (score 5):

`enum` is a special kind of `class ( type)` in `java` which can contain instance fields known as constants and also methods. 
The way you define the constant name violets the rule to define a field in `java`. 
A field must satart with certain characters including a-z , A-Z, _ ( under score) . 
So the arithmetic sign is not allowed as a constant name.

Secondly when you call `4+Op[0]+3`  here you are concatenating the operands with a plus( sign) and expecting an integer value! Its not the way you can expect in java. It looks something like operator overloading .. but Java does not support operator overloading.

In the following example you can overload `Calculator.execute()` as you need. 
For example to get a floating point result you can do :

```
public float execute(float a , Op op, float b ){
 float f=0.0f; 
// TODO
 return f;}...
```

Here is one of the solutions of what you want to achieve in java :

```
public class EnumTest
{

    public static void main (String []args)
    {
        Calculator c=new Calculator();
        int a=c.execute(4,  Op.PLUS,3);
        System.out.println("4 +Op.PLUS +3="+a);
        a=c.execute(4, Op.MINUS, 3);

        System.out.println("4 +Op.MINUS+3="+a);

     // prints 
     // 4 +Op.PLUS +3=7
     //  4 +Op.MINUS +3=1 

    }

}
enum  Op{MINUS, PLUS,MULTIPLY,DIVIDE};

class Calculator
{
public int execute (int operandA, Op op, int operandB)
{
int a=0;
switch(op)
{
case MINUS:
    a=operandA-operandB;
    break;
case PLUS:
    a=operandA+operandB;
    break;
case MULTIPLY: 
    a=operandA*operandB;
    break;
case DIVIDE:
    if(operandB>0) // avoid devideByZero exception 
    a=operandA/operandB;
        break;
}
return a;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest I could come up with:

```
 enum Op implements IntBinaryOperator {
    minus((i,j) -> i-j),plus((i,j) -> i+j);

    @Override
    public int applyAsInt(int left, int right) {
        return op.applyAsInt(left, right);
    }
    final IntBinaryOperator op;
    Op(IntBinaryOperator op) {
        this.op = op;
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
IntBinaryOperator op = Op.minus;
int one = op.applyAsInt(4,3);
```